# How do I give three separate lists three separate columns in a csv file?

Tags: python

I'm trying to output my three lists(the one's stored in word_storage) into a csv file but they all get crammed into the first column of the spreadsheet. Is there a way to give all three of the lists separate columns?

Comment: It sounds like you're not printing a `,` between the values from each list.

Comment: You need to post your code if you want anything more than wild guesses.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have three lists like this,

```
a = list(range(1,4))
b = list(range(2,5))
c = list(range(3,6))
```

You can convert them into a csv file using this,

```
for i in range(len(a)):
  for lst in [a,b,c]:
    csv += f"{lst[i]},"
  csv = csv.rstrip(",")
  csv += "\n"

with open("test.csv", "w+") as f:
  f.write(csv)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Pandas to csv function will be helpful here.

```
 import pandas as pd
 df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['Raphael', 'Donatello'],
                   'mask': ['red', 'purple'],
                   'weapon': ['sai', 'bo staff']})
 df.to_csv(index=False)
```

The above example uses there list and gives a header as Name,mask and weapon